NSIS Removing Unknown Registry Key
I'm creating an installer for an Excel Add-In.
The install adds a value to the Excel Registry tree at:
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Add-in Manager

With is simply the path to the add in, which in turn tells Excel to load it on the add-in list.
When the add in is actually loaded, that is, when the checkmark by the add-in entry is checked and the uses clicks close, Excel deletes that entry and creates one in:
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options\OPEN

Whose value is the path to the add-in.
However, if we have one or more add-ins installed the OPEN can be OPEN1, OPEN2, or whatever number of add-ins have been loaded by the user.
In my NSI file, I wrote the following code on the uninstall:
; Iterates through the registry and unregisters the Add-In from Excel
; set variable $0 to 0
StrCpy $0 0
; loop through the registry
loop:

LogText "Checking registry key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options -> OPEN$0"

; read the registry key. Add $0 if $0 != 0
${If} $0 == 0
    ReadRegStr $1 HKCU "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options" "OPEN"
${Else}
    ReadRegStr $1 HKCU "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options" "OPEN$0"
${EndIf}

; check if the registry key is empty
; if it is empty, leave the loop
${if} $1 == ""
    LogText "Registry key is empty. Exiting loop."
    Goto end
${EndIf}

LogText "Registry value: '$1'"

; check if the registry key contains the path to the Add-In
${If} $1 != "$INSTDIR\MyAddIn.xlam"
    LogText "Not our Add-In. Skipping..."
    Goto next
${Else}
    ${If} $0 == 0
        LogText "Removing registry key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options -> OPEN"
        DeleteRegValue HKCU "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options" "OPEN"
    ${Else}
        LogText "Removing registry key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options -> OPEN$0"
        DeleteRegValue HKCU "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options" "OPEN$0"
    ${EndIf}
    Goto end
${EndIf}

next:

; increment the variable $0
IntOp $0 $0 + 1

; go back to the beginning of the loop
Goto loop

end:

Even though I added the LogText, there is nothing on the log file (install.log on the root of C:) about the uninstall.
Am I doing something wrong here?

Are you able to LogText other things? Is this question about logging or registry?

@Anders I can log and see the log during INSTALL... Uninstall I get nada.

You need to initialize the log filename in the uninstaller as well (IIRC)

@Anders I thought the .onInit function was called for the uninstall too. That's where I initialize the log.

No, that would be un.onInit
